# How to enable the KVM in GCP/DigitalOcean Linux Instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, digital-ocean, virtualization, kvm

I want to enable the KVM in the existing GCP/DigitalOcean Linux Instance.

Comment: What is a KVM - Kernel-based Virtual Machine or remote Keyboard, Video and Mouse? When asking a question, show the research that you have done, the problem you are having and the errors/configuration files/source code to help us reproduce your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, I mean Kernal Based Virtual Machine. I want to know how we can enable Kernal Based Virtual Machine/nested virtualization in Droplets (DigitalOcean).

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is `nested virtualization`, here are the links to the official documentation:

- [enabling vmx](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances)
- [troubleshooting vmx](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-nested-vms)

So if by **existing** you mean **running** (ie without turning it off and doing things to it), I don't think you can, but you can create an image from the existing instance and then create another VM from that image with vms license attached.

Comment: How about the DigitalOcean instance, can we enable KVM in the droplets also?  Existing means instance/droplets are already created but it's in a stop state.